# How to deliver Android/iOS app for Specific Group of users

Tags: android, ios, google-play-console, apple-developer-account

I'm planning to release a mobile app, iOS/Android, to a specific set of users who operate in their personal gmails and apple accounts. In that case, I have to strictly stick to the following conditions.

1. The app should be available only for a specific set of users' personal devices.
2. PlayStore and AppStore registered for their personal emails.
3. Apps shouldn't be a TestFlight or Beta Apps
4. There should be a facility to push app updates to the users
5. There will be around 5,000+ users

Further, we have the following facilities

- Apple Developer program and Apple Enterprise Program
- Google Developer Console
- Firebase with blaze plan

I have gone through Kaspersky MDM, Heka, Citrix, and Apple Business suite. None of those satisfies the total requirements. I'm looking for a solution for app distribution or OTA installation.

Comment: You can use Firebase for specific set of devices. Thanks

Comment: If the user's don't work for the same company or set of companies and then you are probably going to struggle to find a solution on iOS.  You can't deliver apps outside of the App Store or Apple Business Manager that don't expire.  If all users work for the company that holds the enterprise agreement then you could sign using that and distribute from your own web site with an appropriate login. You would need to refresh the app at least once per year and users would need to update their app themselves (unless you have an MDM to push the app to the devices)

Comment: Thanks, @Paulw11 we have MDM, But we can not integrate it with the user's devices. We are going to provide this app to download on their personal devices.  Could you please more explain about the enterprise sign distribution?

Comment: You can distribute an enterprise signed app via a web server. Apple requires you to secure the download in some way; either requiring a username/password or having the server not accessible from the internet.  Watch https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/304